# Launching iOS messenger from phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova

Is there a way to launch the messenger on iOS from an HTML5 app made with PhoneGap?  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invoke another app in an iOS environment by raising a URL request with specific scheme. so to open an email or phone app, in your html,

```
    <a href="tel:+919900600233" class="call mobile"></a>
<a href="mailto:help@domain.com" class="email"></a>
```

When user taps over this hyper link the user will be taken to the respective apps. same way for message app, use

```
<a href="sms:+919900600233" class="SMS"></a>
```

List of all URL schemes : [iOS URL Schemes](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#SMS)

Comment: Is there no possible way to load it up with a custom message?